# create a two dimensional clustered column chart with two levels of categories on the x axis in r without using ggplot

Tags: r, excel, plot, bar-chart

I have a table of data that I can put into a clustered column chart in excel.  I would like to do the same thing but have the chart created in R.  How can this be done?
[Table of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9swkW.png)
[Chart in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69Cx9.png)

I tried the following, and it resulted in the attached chart.  The data is ordered and labeled incorrectly.  ggplot does not work on my machine so is not an option.

```
# Create a data frame with the given data
data <- data.frame(
  City = c("Minneapolis", "Minneapolis", "Minneapolis", "Orlando", "Orlando", "Orlando", 
           "Phoenix", "Phoenix", "Phoenix", "Sacramento", "Sacramento", "Sacramento"),
  Tree_Type = c("No Tree", "Medium Tree", "Large Tree", "No Tree", "Medium Tree", "Large Tree", 
                "No Tree", "Medium Tree", "Large Tree", "No Tree", "Medium Tree", "Large Tree"),
  E_Plus = c(158, 133, 123, 879, 863, 827, 2858, 2812, 2779, 421, 363, 351),
  iTE = c(1354, 1337, 1331, 6057, 6043, 6041, 4356, 4336, 4328, 2125, 2099, 2078)
)

# Set up the positions for bars
bar_width <- 0.35
barplot(
  height = c(data$E_Plus, data$iTE), 
  beside = TRUE, 
  names.arg = paste(data$City, data$Tree_Type), 
  col = c("red", "blue"),
  main = "Energy Consumption by City and Tree Type", 
  ylab = "Energy Consumption", 
  xlab = "City / Tree Type", 
  ylim = c(0, max(data$E_Plus, data$iTE) + 500)  # Adjust the y-axis limits if necessary
)

# Adding legend
legend("topright", legend = c("EnergyPlus", "i-Tree Energy"), fill = c("red", "blue"))

# Adding data labels under the bars
text(
  x = 1:(nrow(data) * 2), 
  y = -50,  # Adjust the vertical position of the labels
  labels = paste(data$City, data$Tree_Type), 
  xpd = TRUE, 
  srt = 45, 
  adj = c(1.2, 1.2), 
  cex = 0.8
)
```

[Incorrect chart from R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQjYK.png)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `matrix` form of `barplot` (i.e. supplying a matrix instead of a vector to `height` - each column represents a bar and each row either a stacked bar or a dodged one alongside (`beside = TRUE`). Then eahc group is already nicely put together with some gaps between groups.

Then you need some fiddling with the labels and you can get pretty close to what Excel is doing:

```r
with(data, {
  op <- par(mar = c(7, 4, 4, 2) + .1) ## make some space for the labels below
  barplot(rbind(E_Plus, iTE), ## use matrix form
          col = c("steelblue", "orange"),
          beside = TRUE
  )
  ## Tree_Type below each group
  text(seq(2, by = 3, length.out = 12), par("usr")[3] - .25, 
       srt = 90, adj = 1, xpd = TRUE,
       labels = Tree_Type) ## xpd = TRUE to put labels outside the plotting area
  ## City centered below each group of three Tree_Types
  text(seq(5, by = 9, length.out = 4), par("usr")[3] - 1500, 
       xpd = TRUE, labels = unique(City))
  x <- seq(.5, by = 9, length.out = 5)
  ## lines as in the Excel variant
  segments(x, 0, x, par("usr")[3] - 1700, col = "lightgray", xpd = TRUE)
  par(op)
})
```

[image: Grouped Barcplot with lines in the margin to separate groups]

Answer (score 1):

We can `reshape` the data and use some algorithms to avoid hard-coding (as much as possible).

```
r <- reshape(data, idvar='Tree_Type', timevar='City', v.names=c('E_Plus', 'iTE'),
             direction='w') |>
  {\(.) `rownames<-`(.[, -1], .[, 1])}() |> as.matrix()

sq <- seq_len(ncol(r)); .clr <- c('#2297e6', '#ffa500')

par(mar=c(10, 4, 4, 2))

plot.new()
plot.window(c(2.5, prod(dim(r))*2.15), c(range(r)))
lapply(seq(0, max(r), 1e3), \(i) abline(h=i, col='gray80'))
b <- barplot(unlist(lapply(unique(data$City), \(x) t(r[, grep(x, colnames(r))]))), 
             space=c(2, .25), col=.clr, legend.text=c('E+', 'iTE'), las=1, add=T)
mtext(rownames(r), 1, 0.5, at=colMeans(matrix(b, 2)), las=2)
mtext(unique(data$City), 1, 6, at=colMeans(matrix(b, 6)), las=1, col=8)
b2 <- matrix(b[-1, ], 2) |> suppressWarnings()
n <- nrow(r)
pos <- colMeans(b2[, seq_len(ncol(b2)) %% n == 0][, 1:n])
.d <- diff(tail(pos, 2))
pos <- c(pos[1] - .d, pos, pos[length(pos)] + .d)
segments(pos, 0, pos, -.26e4, xpd=TRUE, col='gray80')
```

[image]

It's a pity that `barplot` does not yet have a `panel.first=` argument!

---

*Data:*

```
data <- structure(list(City = c("Minneapolis", "Minneapolis", "Minneapolis", 
"Orlando", "Orlando", "Orlando", "Phoenix", "Phoenix", "Phoenix", 
"Sacramento", "Sacramento", "Sacramento"), Tree_Type = c("No Tree", 
"Medium Tree", "Large Tree", "No Tree", "Medium Tree", "Large Tree", 
"No Tree", "Medium Tree", "Large Tree", "No Tree", "Medium Tree", 
"Large Tree"), E_Plus = c(158, 133, 123, 879, 863, 827, 2858, 
2812, 2779, 421, 363, 351), iTE = c(1354, 1337, 1331, 6057, 6043, 
6041, 4356, 4336, 4328, 2125, 2099, 2078)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```